# Upgrading transactional send definition to create Transactional Send journey fails

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, transactional-messaging-api

I have previously created a Send Definition using the [Transactional Send API endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createSendDefinition.htm), but I realized after creating the definition that `createJourney` wasn't set to true.

I am trying to update the definition using this [endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updateMessageDefinition.htm), and using the following payload:
URL (PATCH): /messaging/v1/email/definitions/AccountTriggerv1

```
{
  "content": {
    "customerKey": "371f6ba4-db9d-4114-a7f9-XXXXXX"
  },
  "options": {
    "createJourney": true
  },
  "subscriptions": {
    "list": "All Subscribers - XXXX",
    "dataExtension": "2814D4EF-FD23-4FC2-A95C-XXXXXX",
    "autoAddSubscriber": true,
    "updateSubscriber": true
  }
}
```

The is what I get back:

```
{
    "requestId": "61ce8c34-5f47-4461-a288-XXXXXXX",
    "name": "Account Trigger v1",
    "definitionKey": "AccountTriggerv1",
    "description": "Account Trigger v1",
    "classification": "XXX",
    "status": "Active",
    "createdDate": "2020-11-19T07:35:00",
    "modifiedDate": "2020-12-03T10:57:00",
    "content": {
        "customerKey": "371f6ba4-db9d-4114-a7f9-XXXXX"
    },
    "subscriptions": {
        "dataExtension": "2814D4EF-FD23-4FC2-A95C-XXXXXXX",
        "list": "All Subscribers - 10228",
        "autoAddSubscriber": true,
        "updateSubscriber": true
    },
    "options": {
        "trackLinks": true
    },
    "journey": {
        "status": "Error",
        "message": "The Transactional Journey failed to update.  Please retry via a PATCH request or contact our help desk for further assistance."
    }
}
```

The update call was a PATCH request so I'm not sure why it's failing. Can someone advise what to do? (without having to reach out to Salesforce)

Comment: My best guess, without testing, is that the Transactional Send should be inactive in order to be adjusted. In the example on the documentation there is "status": "Inactive" set.

Comment: There are some inactive send definitions I have tried to update, that also throw the same error.

Comment: Do you have an aversion to Salesforce Support? Or why do you exclude them from the beginning? (Or have you already reached out to them)

Comment: Usually takes a week before I get to a support tier that knows the answer.. so my usual order to get things answered is stack exchange and the SF support.

Comment: I duplicated your exact situation and it worked without issue on my end. I am guessing the issue is something that SFMC Support will need to investigate. Perhaps there is some sort of permission issue or BR that is preventing you from utilizing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be a permission issue after all, the integration didn't have CRUD permissions for Journeys.

Comment: hi, could you mention which permission you needed to add here?

Answer (score 1):

Since the posted answer was not clear enough. Am just posting this answer just in case if some one is looking in future.

When It is throwing the below error due in Transactional API

```
"journey": {
        "status": "Error",
        "message": "The Transactional Journey failed to update.  Please retry via a PATCH request or contact our help desk for further assistance."
    }
```

Make sure you have all the necessary permissions in Install package for Journey Builder.

[image]